# Searching a .txt file Against Output

Tags: c, passwords

I've made a password generator... then generates a password of 12 Characters, and then saves the password to a .txt file.
I want to be able to search the .txt file so no two passwords are ever created identical.
I honestly have no idea how to go about this and would really appreciate some help.

I have the password generator working, and the passwords are saving fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>


FILE*fp; 

char *symbols = "#~!$%^&*()+=<>?/@"; // Random Symbol is generated form this list

int main(void) {

    char password[4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 1]; // 4 Upper, 4 Lower, 2 Num, 2 Symbols
    int i, j=0, len=sizeof(password)-1;
    int menuNum = 0;
    char passwordCheck[15+1];

    fp = fopen("passwords.txt", "a+"); //Opens the text file to save the Passwords

    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("       Main Menu\n");
    printf("********************************\n");
    printf("\nEnter 1 to Generate a New Password: ");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Enter 2 to Check Old Passwords: ");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Enter 3 to Exit. ");
    printf("\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &menuNum); // reads number

    if (menuNum == 1) // If 1 is entered on the Menu...
    {
        printf("********************************\n");
        printf("\nYour New Password is: \n\n");

    // Each Password will Have 12 Characters(4 Uppercase letters, 4 Lowercase letters, 2 Numbers & 2 Symbols)

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        password[j++] = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1); // Generates 4 random Lowercase characters 

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        password[j++] = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1); // Generates 4 random Uppercase characters

    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        password[j++] = '0' + rand() % ('0' - '9' + 1); // Generates 2 random numbers

    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        password[j++] = symbols[rand() % strlen(symbols)]; // Generates 2 random symbols

    password[j] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(password)-1; ++i)
        {
        char c = password[i];
        j = rand() % len;
        password[i] = password[j];
        password[j] = c;
        } // Shuffles passwords Characters

    printf("%s\n\n", password);
    printf("********************************\n");
    fprintf(fp, "\n%s", password); // Outputs the Generated Passoword to the text file
    fclose(fp); // Closes the text file
    system("pause");
    }

    else if (menuNum == 2)
    {           
        printf("\nEnter your password for checking: ");
        printf("%s", passwordCheck);  // reads password
        if (strlen(passwordCheck) > 15) // Checks length of Password
        {
            printf("'%s' is too long. Needs to be less then 15 Characters\n", passwordCheck);
            system("pause");
        }
        else if (strlen(passwordCheck) < 9) //Checks length of Password
        {
            printf("'%s' is too short. Needs to be more then 9 Characters\n", passwordCheck);
            system("pause");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you can open the file, read a line [password], use `strcmp()`? read it [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: hmm...I dunno...How I would go about comparing the outputted password against a .txt file using that. :/

Comment: For this you will have to scan whole file and also you will have to compare the each password with your new password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read all the bytes in the file one by one and save characters in some kind of buffer until you encounter a newline character. Then compare all the bytes in the buffer to your to be added password, if it's the same, the password is already in the file. Clear the buffer and read until the next newline character. Repeat untill the end of the file.